# FormData на IE 11

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, formdata

Появилась проблема на IE11, он ни в какую не хочет работать с FormData.
Пробовал определять его разными способами:

```js
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
///
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', 'Chris');
///
```

И разными комбинациями из этих способов. Но IE всегда отправляет пустые данные (да и в целом насколько я понял FormData всегда пустой, т.е. значения не добавляются), при этом на всех остальных браузерах все работает как надо.

Код отправки:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: url,
    data:  formData, 

});
```

Что от меня хочет IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> contentType: false,
> ```

Предлагаю заполнить или вообще убрать.

```
contentType: "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, выдает "Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0".

Comment: Если убрать, по отправляет данные в таком виде: "-----------------------------7df33f3a101ae Content-Disposition: form-data; name=&amp;quot;name&amp;quot; name", т.е. не чистый post.

Comment: Хотелось бы получать чистый post, но раз уж такое дело. Воспользовался http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483851/manually-parse-raw-http-data-with-php что бы распарсить "multipart/form-data".

Comment: @Denis, чем это он не чистый? Он вроде так и должен выглядеть при этом формате.

Comment: У меня все post запросы приходят уже в распарсенов виде, что очень удобно, теперь придется в определенных местах делать это самому.

Comment: Но это кстати не решило проблему с тем что $_FILES пустой, хотя в FormData есть файлы.